# Modulo equivalences

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

My homework this week in abstract algebra is focusing on modulos, and basic proofs with them. The proof says 
Suppose that $x\equiv 4\pmod 6$ . Prove that $x\equiv 0\pmod 2$ .

I know that if you have $B\pmod C $ and you increase B by a multiple of C, it stays the same. I'm just not sure how to go about proving this because it only shares an A term in common.

Comment: Hint: $\;2 \mid 6 \mid x-4\,$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $ $ We know from grade school that the parity (even or oddness) of an integer is the same as its units digit $\,a,\,$  i.e. $\,x \equiv a\pmod{\!10}\,\Rightarrow\, x\equiv a\pmod{\!2}.\,$  This reason that this  works is because congruences remain true modulo any $\rm\color{#c00}{factor}$ of the modulus, i.e.

$ x\equiv a\pmod{\!k\color{#c00}n}\,\Rightarrow\,x\equiv a\pmod{\! \color{#c00}n}\ $ by $\,n \mid kn\mid x\!-\!a\,\Rightarrow\, n\mid x\!-\!a\,$ by transitivity of "divides".

So $\, x\equiv 4\pmod{\!3\cdot \color{#c00}2}\,\Rightarrow\, x\equiv 4\pmod{\!\color{#c00}2}\,\Rightarrow\, x \equiv\, \ldots \pmod{\!2}$

Answer (score 1):

Since $x\equiv 4\mod 6$ you can write $x=6a+4=2(3a+2)$ with $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, hence $x\equiv 0\mod 2$, because it is devisable by 2. (2 can be factored out)